# Type conversion from BYTE* to int* in VS C++

Tags: visual-c++

I have 2 sample programs. One converts a WAV into an MP3. Another captures my speakers and writes a WAV file. I try to combine the 2: input speakers, output MP3. My result is a MP3 file of correct length (so I passed the correct number of integers) but with only noise (so I passed the wrong data)
The working conversion source Wav to Mp3:

```
    short int pcm_buffer[PCM_SIZE*2];
    unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];
    read = fread(pcm_buffer, 2 * sizeof(short int), PCM_SIZE, pcm);
    write=lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(gfp, pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
    size_t lBytesWritten = fwrite(mp3_buffer, write, sizeof(char), mp3);
```

The working encoding in Wav is:

```
    BYTE *pData;
    hr = pAudioCaptureClient->GetBuffer( &pData, &nNumFramesToRead, &dwFlags,  NULL, NULL);
    LONG lBytesToWrite = nNumFramesToRead * nBlockAlign;
    mmioWrite(hFile, reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(pData), lBytesToWrite);
```

My version is:

```
    BYTE *pData;
    unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];
    hr = pAudioCaptureClient->GetBuffer( &pData, &nNumFramesToRead, &dwFlags,  NULL, NULL);
    LONG lBytesToMP3=lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(gfp, reinterpret_cast<short int*>(pData), nNumFramesToRead, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
    fwrite(mp3_buffer, lBytesToMP3, sizeof(char), mp3);
```

I don't see the error. I coded C++ until some 10 years ago in Borland C++, and see now that Microsoft protects the world against incompetent programmers. But (I'm really sorry) I don't know how they want me to do it right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
LONG lBytesToMP3=lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(gfp, reinterpret_cast<short int*>(pData), nNumFramesToRead, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
```

You are passing 8-bit sound data to `lame_encode_buffer_interleaved` when it is designed to take 16-bit sound data. The fact that you are casting your data via `reinterpret_cast<short int*>(pData)` should make it clear.

You need to actually pass in 16-bit sound samples.

If you can capture 16-bit samples from the input, that's best. If not, converting from 8-bit samples to 16-bit samples is easy. You just scale the values up! Make sure you handle signedness correctly.

Comment: If I debug the Wav encoder, I see that he writes a BYTE-stream of data as a PCHAR-stream to mmioWrite. If I debug the WAV to MP3 encoder I see that the WAV data is 16-bit (short int) numbers. I get them as BYTE from the AudioClient and need to send them (as is) to Lame, but this time as short int array.  So the samples (because the 2 programs work correctly) must actually be 16-bit. I'm probably messing up an & or * too many or too few

Comment: After many attempts, I finally found out what's happening. It's your 8 bits, that brought me to look closer: actually it's 32 bit float, which I pass as 16 int, You were too close not to get the points!

Comment: Awesome. Congrats on figuring it out!